# Error code uploading a reference image. (screenshot included)

Tags: error

Following Blender Guru's donut tutorial, adding a reference image for a coffee mug he included in the video but it gives me this error instead. Tried my own images, still same error. Not sure how to copy/paste the actual text, sorry. Here's the screenshot:[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using the official release version of Blender 2.80? If not please update and check if that resolves the problem.